# An error occurred executing the click atom

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Using C# and Selenium, I am building an automated script where I, amongst other things, try to select a certain value from a droplist (value being specified in a .csv-file). I get the error;

"**An error occurred executing the click atom** (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)"

I have no idea what a click atom is, much less how to fix it... Any help is appreciated greatly!

thanks in advance

this is the code for the droplist:

```
public bool isellHOSelectAdultsDroplist(string adults)
{
    writeToLog(String.Format("Selecting adults from drop list"), this.GetType().Name);
    String xpathString = HO_ADULT_SELECTION;

    if(GpoExplicitWaitXpathElement(xpathString, 3, 5))
    {
        IWebElement dropListObjects = webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(xpathString));
        writeToLog(String.Format("DEBUG: Trying to click on appropriate number of adults..."), this.GetType().Name);
        selectValueFromAdultDropList(dropListObjects, adults);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

//...and this is my select-method

```
private void selectValueFromAdultDropList(IWebElement dropListObjects, string adults)
{

    SelectElement manipulateDroplistObject = new SelectElement(dropListObjects);
    manipulateDroplistObject.SelectByValue(adults);
    String selection = manipulateDroplistObject.SelectedOption.Text;

    int numberOfElements = manipulateDroplistObject.Options.Count;
    writeToLog("Number of elements in Adult Droplist: " + numberOfElements, this.GetType().Name);
    writeToLog("Selection from adult droplist: " + selection, this.GetType().Name);
}
```

Comment: What's the full stack trace? What line does the error occur? What browser? What version of that browser? What version of Selenium?

Comment: no stack trace (hence the warning...;)); the error occurs on the line SelectElement manipulateDroplistObject = new SelectElement(dropListObjects); in the select-method; browser is IE9 v9.0.8112.16421; Selenium server version 2.25.0;

This way of selecting objects on the same droplist works fine 90% of the time, that's whats bugging me... :)

Comment: For one, I'd suggest updating to v2.30 of Selenium. v2.25 is quite old.

Comment: okay, I will try that. Btw; what is a click atom? :D

Comment: Okay, I have now updated driver to 2.30.0... The error in the clock atom has now spread to other test cases previously unaffected. :(

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer the specific question you asked, which is, "What is a click atom?" There is quite a bit of functionality in the IE driver, and the implementation of this functionality rests on three pillars.

First is IE's COM interfaces. These are the objects and methods that have been used to automate various parts of IE for more than a decade.

The second technology is so-called "native events." That is, using OS-level mechanisms to perform user interactions, like key presses and mouse clicks. On Windows, that means using the Windows SendMessage API. Almost anytime you're using the keyboard or the mouse with the IE driver, you're using native events by default.

Finally, a good portion of the IE driver functionality is implemented using JavaScript functions, which are shared by all of the browsers. These functions are known as "[automation atoms](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AutomationAtoms)".

One of the very few exceptions to using native events for mouse operations is in selecting an `<option>` element from a `<select>` element. Since IE doesn't give discoverable dimensions to `<option>` elements, the IE driver is forced to simulate the click action via JavaScript. This means using the automation *atom* for the click action. In your case, something must've gone wrong executing that JavaScript, which was faithfully reported as a "failure to execute the click atom." Without more detail, including sample HTML pages to reproduce the issue, it will be exceedingly difficult to diagnose the root cause of the issue.

It's at this point I will echo the call to update to the latest IE driver. Some of the code in this area has been overhauled, and at the least, it should be possible to extract more precise errors from failure cases with a more recent driver.

Comment: Thank you! I'm quite new to the automation site of testing and developing, so info like this is most welcome! :)